# Looking for tawus ajaxupload jar

Tags: maven, tapestry, ajax-upload

I want to utilize tawus ajaxupload component for my tapestry web app. I've added dependency to pom.xml, but it looks like the repo already missing. Can someone point me how to get the jar file?

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>com.googlecode.tawus</groupId> 
    <artifactId>tawus-ajaxupload</artifactId> 
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have my doubts that you use a `SNAPSHOT`...I would suggest to use a release...

Comment: I think the artifact itself is already missing from the repo...

Comment: The question is what you mean by: `missing from the repo...` which would imply that it had been there ...then we come to the point in which repository ? Maven Central ?

Comment: I mean it looks like it's already deleted from repository. No longer exist.

Comment: If we are talking about a release this will never happen...a SNAPSHOT is of course something different... This could it be: https://github.com/tawus/tawus but 7 years no commit..a release on Github not to central etc.